# Is it still possible to delete all of my Facebook posts without closing my Facebook account?

Tags: facebook

I want to delete everything from my Facebook account (including, ideally, posts I've made on other people's walls) but keep the account open. It seems that there used to be some scripts that would do this, but that these scripts no longer works. Searching Stack Exchange throws up a few answers that refer to writing a Facebook application. Is this now the only way to do this, or are there scripts or similar that will do this for me?

Comment: It is not possible to delete all the posts all in one go...But you can delete the page (Go to Page Setting, go to the bottom ➣ Remove Page.)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to write a Facebook application that leverages using a Facebook user access token belonging to a Facebook native not a third party. Third party application cannot delete all posts.

Even then you might run into a rate limit.